# Does mongoose still have reactivity issues with meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoose

I want to use mongoose in my meteor app for validation and also because I am quite comfortable with it coming from Node background. I read at multiple places that using mongoose gives 10 sec delay in comparison to using Meteor's in-built Mongo driver. But on this question ([Meteor.js and Mongoose Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854804/meteor-js-and-mongoose-compatibility)), it says

> EDIT: As of December 2013, Meteor's Mongo package listens to Mongo's
>   oplog, and will reflect any changes done by external mongoose activity
>   in real-time.

Is it true that reactivity issues with mongoose has been solved? If not, is there any other package I can use? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't find article on Meteor blog, but yes, there is no more problem with reactivity, changes are pushed on instant, not after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look at [aldeed:simple-schema](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/simple-schema) and possibly even aldeed:collection2 and aldeed:autoform. Their functionality is not a direct overlap, but they give you similar schema validation capability as mongoose.